# How to create an excel spreadsheet with an excel add-in installed in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus, excel-addins

I have created an excel spreadsheet using [epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) library.

In this spreadsheet there are few columns with drop downs.

I need to make these drop downs searchable. 
We can make a drop down applied on a single cell, searchable using excel functions.

But it is not possible to apply the same on all the cells within a column.

But this is achievable using excel add-ins like 'excel campus-the-list-search-add-in' (https://members.excelcampus.com/products/the-list-search-add-in/categories/142180/posts/422610).

I don't want each and every user to install the excel add-in when they are using the spreadsheet created from my application.

I want the add-in to be automatically added, when creating the spreadsheet from my .NET application using epplus library.

Comment: Epplus generates the raw xml and zips it up (xlsx is just a renamed .zip file) without Excel so it has no access to the DOM/Application.  You should confirm with the devs on their github page but I think that is far beyond its capability.  Since you have the asp.net tag I assume you are generating this through a web site so it cannot do any kind of install for the plug in.  Is VBA an option?  There can be security hoops to jump through but if the plugin can be install that way then you can embed the code into the EPPlus-generated file and have it fire on start.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit confusing!
maybe this can help you:

```
//Create the data set and table
DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
DataTable dt = new DataTable("New_DataTable");

//Set the locale for each
ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
dt.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

//Open a DB connection (in this example with OleDB)
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(dbConnectionString);
con.Open();

//Create a query and fill the data table with the data from the DB
string sql = "SELECT Whatever FROM MyDBTable;";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
OleDbDataAdapter adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter();

adptr.SelectCommand = cmd;
adptr.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

//Add the table to the data set
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

//Here's the easy part. Create the Excel worksheet from the data set
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", ds);
```

Comment: I know how to create the excel spreadsheet from a data set in .NET. But I need to create the excel spreadsheet with an excel add-in added automatically. So the excel downloaded from my application has data as well as this add-in added to it.